# Mysql matching one or more spaces

Tags: mysql, substring

I have a **string column** named "matches" that has data like this:

```
054T,Arequipa,Peru
```

I am using a query for extracting a substring, for example extracting the first appearing term:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(matches, ',', 1)
```

that succesfully returns 054T. Now the problem is that I have data that is separated by one or more spaces:

```
054T     Arequipa    Peru
```

and:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(matches, ' ', 1)
```

does not return 054T, what would be the regex like dilimiter for one or more spaces ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT LEFT(matches, LOCATE(' ', matches) - 1);
```

`LOCATE` returns an index (1-based) of the first whitespace symbol, and with `LEFT` you just take that number of symbols from your string's left side.

And this snippet will return the value itself when there's no whitespace in it:

```
SELECT IF(
  LOCATE(' ', matches) != 0, 
  LEFT(matches, LOCATE(' ', matches) - 1), 
  matches
);
```

---

And if, as you mentioned, there can be both spaces and tabs, just prepare the string accordingly:

```
SELECT LEFT(matches, LOCATE(' ', REPLACE(matches, '\t', ' ')) - 1);
```

Still I wonder, can't you just normalize it:

```
UPDATE your_table SET matches = REPLACE(matches, '\t', REPEAT(' ', 4));
```

... or, perhaps better, just move it into another table (as it really looks like a set in disguise at present).

Comment: great that worked, but now I see a case where not only multiple spaces appear but a tab '\t' what would work for both cases, spaces and/or tabs.

Comment: Sigh... are you sure you shouldn't just normalize your data instead? Will update my answer.

Comment: I could normalize, it's 13M rows, I woul love if you can help me.